# Upper bound for prime counting function $\pi(x)$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

Let $\pi(x)$ denote the number of primes less than or equal to $x$. I want to prove 
$$ \pi(x) \leq \frac{9x\log 2}{\log x} $$
for every integer $x\geq 2$. In the problem (from Murty's $\textit{Algebraic Number Theory}$), I have been given the following hint
$$ \prod_{n<p\leq 2n} p \mid {2n\choose n}  $$
but I can't seem to apply it in a usefull way.

I would prefer a subtle hint for the solution, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I didn't make any mistake, from $\sum_{n \le p \le 2n} \ln p \le \ln {2n \choose n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln(n+k) - \ln k  < \int_{n+1}^{2n+1} \ln x dx-\int_1^{n} \ln x dx$ you get 
 $$\sum_{n \le p \le 2n} \ln p < 2n\ln2+\ln(n)+1$$ can you finish from there ?

Comment: You can find a proof that implies this result in Apostol, Introduction to analytic number theory, page $82$ theorem $4.6$.